# Prove that $|z||b-ad| \leq M $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to prove the following statement:
$$
|z||\frac{az + b}{z+d}-a| <= M
$$
with $a,b,c,z \in \mathbb{C}, |z| \geq 1 + |d|$ and $M\geq 0$. I have reduced this to
$$
|z||b-ad| \leq M
$$
Also $ad -b \neq 0$. I don't know how to proceed my proof.

Comment: The problem searches for an upperbound for the Mobius transform.

Comment: Please state what is known / unknown. Are you trying to prove that given $a,b,d$, there exists $M$ such that $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|\geq 1+|d|$, you have the above inequality ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
|z|\big|\frac{az+b}{z+d}-a\big|
&=& |z|\big|\frac{az+b}{z+d}-\frac{az+ad}{z+d}\big| \\
&=& |z|\big|\frac{b-ad}{z+d}\big| \\
&=& |b-ad|\big|\frac{z}{z+d}\big| \\
&=& |b-ad|\big|1-\frac{d}{z+d}\big| \\
&\leq & |b-ad|\bigg(1+\frac{|d|}{|z+d|}\bigg) \\
&\leq & |b-ad|\bigg(1+\frac{|d|}{|z|-|d|}\bigg) \\
&\leq & |b-ad|\bigg(1+|d|\bigg)
\end{array}
$$

So you can take $M=|b-ad|\bigg(1+|d|\bigg)$.